# click event not triggered at the first click in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a main.php inside which another page (page1.php) is being called embedded in a div.
I am dynamically updating the a table in page1 when the page1.php is loaded.

Now when I call a function on the click event of the table the function is called but the control doesn't enters in the click event of the table which I have called inside the function.
However clicking the second time onwards the control enters and works fine.

Following is the function in the js file

```
function highlight_table()
{
$(#table tr).click(function(){
alert("here");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are calling this function when the DOM is loaded so that the event handler is attached the first time:

```
$(function() {
    highlight_table();
});
```

If the `table` is not present when the DOM is loaded but is later added using AJAX you might need to call this function in the `success` handler of your AJAX request.

Also you might need to use the [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) function so that when the table is updated the click handler is preserved (if needed):

```
$('#table tr').live('click', function() {
    alert('here');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to look into the `.delegate()` function as from what I've read, the creators of jQuery seem to be pushing users towards that over `.live()`.