# JQuery Problem With Link Click

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I've got a little project I'm working on.

I've got a problem with the reply links found on the page.  The problem only occurs with Firefox.  I've tested on Google Chrome but, no problem.

Ideally, when I click the reply link, the topmost sharebox dissapears and the reply box appears under the comment to reply to.

When I click the reply link of any comment on Google chrome, the topmost sharebox disappears **immediately** and the replybox appears simultaneously.

however, in Firefox, on the **first click**, nothing happens except that the topmost sharebox loses focus.  On **second click**, the topmost sharebox disappears and the replybox shows.

My problem is:  why does it require two clicks for it to work in Firefox?  I want it to work with only the first click.

Comment: Have you tested in Safari, IE and/or opera?  This could lend some important information (works in webkit, etc)

Comment: can you share some of the code that's doing the hiding and showing

Comment: Your link is not working in chrome itself !

Comment: The code's a mess, but it's been added above.

Comment: tested in Windows 7 IE (version?)  - same problem.

Comment: I'm sure the problem's with the above code.  Just can't put my finger on it...

Comment: Where are you getting error ? Do you think this mess code (as you said) would be understandable ?

Comment: try alert() & find where you stops ?

Comment: I've just tried something.  I've added an alert in the click function. just after $("a.reply").click(function() { and found out that the alert isn't even triggered.  This means that the click handler isn't even being called the first time the link is being clicked

Comment: also saw some else having similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491917/click-event-not-triggered-at-the-first-click-in-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That `remove()` is executed after fadeOut is complete. (Browser doesn't wait, keep executing next lines)

So when browser considers that fadeOut is complete, removes the `$('#comment_form')`. That in the case of slow browsers has been filled already with the new form?

So try without fadeOut to see if works like that, keeping executing of that code chronologically.

Comment: I've tried removing it directly, with the fadeout, still doesn't work... :(

Comment: If you want to keep the fadeout, put the insert of new comment form  `fadeOut(0,function({ HERE });`

Comment: I've just tried something.  I've added an alert in the click function. just after $("a.reply").click(function() { and found out that the alert isn't even triggered.  This means that the click handler isn't even being called the first time the link is being clicked

Comment: That can be because click() is static. Try binding the event like this: $("a.reply").live('click', function(

Comment: Ok, I have download it and tested and seems the problem is with the plugin elastic. If you remove it, it will work. It blocks somehow the capture of the click event